# Problem with calling PayPal DO_DIRECT_PAYMENT: com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.FatalException: Unable to complete HTTPS transaction

Tags: java, maven, paypal

I am working on integrating `DO_DIRECT_PAYMENT` on a java application. I have the following maven dependencies in the project pom.xml file.

```
<!-- PayPal SDK Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>paypal-base</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am trying to create a simple integration test that works successfully.

Below is the test client class:

```
public class PaypalServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldDoASuccessfullDirectPayment() throws PayPalException {
        //execute
        PaypalService paypalService = new PaypalService();
        //verify
        paypalService.doDirectPayment();
    }

}
```

Below is the SUT(class under test):

```
public class PaypalService {

   public void doDirectPayment() throws PayPalException {
        NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
        encoder.add("VERSION","72.0"); 
        encoder.add("METHOD", "DoDirectPayment"); 
        encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION", "SALE"); 
        encoder.add("AMT", "20.0"); // value: 20.00
        encoder.add("CREDITCARDTYPE",creditCardType); // value: type of credit card(Amex| MasterCard etc...)
        encoder.add("ACCT", creditCardNumber); // value: test  credit card no
        encoder.add("CVV2", cvv2Number); // value: test cvv2, 4 digit for amex, three digit for master card 
        encoder.add("EXPDATE", "11/2023");
        encoder.add("FIRSTNAME", "Test1"); 
        encoder.add("LASTNAME", "Test2"); 
        encoder.add("ADDRESS1", "Test Address); 
        encoder.add("CITY","Test City); 
        encoder.add("STATE","USA"); 
        encoder.add("ZIP",""02110"); 
        encoder.add( "COUNTRYCODE", "USA"); 
        encoder.add( "CURRENCYCODE", "USD"); 
        encoder.add( "IPADDRESS" , ipAddress); //my IP address
        encoder.add( "EMAIL", email);// value: empty

        String request = encoder.encode();

        APIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
        profile.setAPIUsername(API_USERNAME); // value: useraneme
        profile.setAPIPassword(API_PASSWORD); // value: password
        profile.setSignature(API_SIGNATURE); // value: signature
        profile.setEnvironment(API_ENVIRONMENT); // value: Sandbox

        NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
        caller.setAPIProfile(profile);

        String response = caller.call(request);


   }
}
```

When I run the test, I am having the error below:

```
com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.FatalException: Unable to complete HTTPS transaction

    at com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPAPICaller.call(NVPAPICaller.java:372)
    at com.paypal.sdk.services.NVPCallerServices.call(NVPCallerServices.java:56)
    at io.dexi.paypal.PaypalService.doDirectPayment(PaypalService.java:73)
    at io.dexi.paypal.PaypalServiceTest.shouldDoASuccessfullDirectPayment(PaypalServiceTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.FatalException: HTTP Error code 400 received, transaction not submitted
    at com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPAPICaller.call(NVPAPICaller.java:355)
    ... 25 more
```

I will appreciate any help or guide in solving this issue.

Regards,
Rando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost a couple of hours with this issue. As I thought, the problem was a mistake in the request parameters that I sent to Paypal.

I fixed this by modifying the format of EXPDATE like below:

```
// encoder.add("EXPDATE", "11/2023");
encoder.add("EXPDATE", "112023");
```